# Continuity of $f$ such that $\forall x \leq 0, f(x) = x$ and $\forall x>0, f(x) = x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, continuity

As far as I know, a real function is said to be *continuous* at some point $a$ whenever $\lim_{x\to a} = f(a)$. Now, given the function 
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},f(x) = \begin{cases} x\ ,&&  x\leq 0\\x\sin(\frac{1}{x})\ , &&x>0 \end{cases}$$
we see that actually $$\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x) =\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)= f(0) = 0$$

Nevertheless, assuming $f$ to be continuous at $0$ seems very counter-intuitive. Is this function really continuous at $0$ and thus continuous everywhere? Am I wrong in my reasoning?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is it counter-intuitive? Here is its plot: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BPiecewise%5B%7B%7Bx%2C+x+%3C%3D+0%7D%2C+%7Bx*sin%281%2Fx%29%2C+x+%3E+0%7D%7D%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+-0.5%2C+0.5%7D%5D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition of continuity. And even this might seem counterintuitive, since both $x$ for $x \leq 0$ and $x sin(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x > 0$ are continuous and both left- and rightside limits in $0$ are equal (and equal to function value in that point), the function is continuous everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed continuous at $0$, for exactly the reason you stated. It is also continuous away from $0$ since the functions $x$ and $x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ are continuous away from $0$. So it is continuous everywhere.

Maybe looking at a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9bdh4russe) will help you see that this function is continuous?